# How to create a container control

Tags: user-controls, containers

I am a newbie to here, excuse my ignorance if this is a FAQ.

For a Windows Phone 7 / Silverlight application, I want to create a custom container control, that will host other controls -- much like a ListBox or a StackPanel.

Please point me in the right direction. any Code Samples will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `StackPanel` and `Grid` for this. Here's an interesting link that provides [Layout Tips and Tricks](http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/tutorials/windows-phone-7/layout-tips/) for Windows Phone 7 App development.

Comment: something like that -- but, **custom**, **built from scratch**. My intention is to learn how to create a control that can contain other controls, not to use preexisting ones.